# Get row values programmatically from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView Control and one button:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" >        
    <Columns>             
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Balance">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("Balance") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>     
</asp:GridView>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID ="btn" Text ="test"/>
```

Then on load page, I populate the gridView with a list of agreements. on that list there are one field called "Balance":

```
    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load
    Dim agreementManager As AgreementManager = New AgreementManager()

    Dim lstBalances As List(Of Agreement) = agreementManager.GetByClientId(2)

    grdView.DataSource = lstBalances
    grdView.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Then it display me this after loaded:

[image: Balance]

I am trying to read programmatically one specific balance with:

```
Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click

    Dim value As String = grdView.Rows(1).Cells(0).Text

End Sub
```

But the "value" is empty.

What I am doing wrong?

I am working on mock a system that uses this way to read the values from a grid view, and this code works fine:

```
Dim balance As Decimal =        
   CType(grdApplyTransactionsAgreements.Rows(idx).Cells(BALANCE_CELLID).Text, Decimal)
```

this code is inside a button too.

Thanks!!

Comment: `I am trying to read programmatically` Where are you reading it from?

Comment: From the gridView Control

Comment: Inside what event of GridView? Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bumped into an answer, I need to use BondField Control instead Template Field, now everything runs fine.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" >        
      <Columns>                          
          <asp:BoundField  DataField ="Balance" HeaderText ="Balance"/>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The .Text property can only be read after DataBinding from `AutoGenerated` columns and `BoundField` columns. But even if you could I would not recommend it since all you are getting is a string, not the original datatype.

Better read the values from the source `lstBalances`.